# Why Math.max with an Array Returns NaN in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to Javascript. I have already tried to find information on the Internet and on publics, but have not yet come to an answer.

Guys, who knows why the program outputs NaN?

Javascript code:

```
let arr = [9, 23, 0, -24.5, 34, 11, 41, 3, -3.2, 3];
let arrmax = Math.max(arr);
console.log(arrmax);
```

ChatGPT writes that there are no errors and that the answer should be 41.

But when I write the code in one line like this, it works:

```
console.log("Largest number:", Math.max(9, 23, 0, -24.5, 34, 11, 41, 3, -3.2, 3));
```

Comment: because `Math.max`does not accept an array as a parameter, it [accepts 0 or more values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#parameters) and arrays are not numbers. Try logging the value of `isNaN([1,2,3])`.

Comment: Have we learned our lesson about asking ChatGPT?

Comment: `Math.max.apply(Math, arr)` or ES6 (@Barmar) `Math.max(...arr)`

Comment: The duplicate question has almost the same title as yours. How did you miss it when you searched before posting? I found it with the search string `[javascript] math.max array`